# Cropping images to square in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: forms, xamarin, xamarin.forms, crop

I'm trying to get a user to select/take a picture and then getting a crop view up. I have managed to do this using this library:
https://github.com/XAM-Consulting/Xam.Plugins.ImageCropper

But I want to force the image to be a square, not any aspect ratio the user pleases. Is there anyone who knows how to do this?

Is there any other library/plugin that I can use for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this: https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls/tree/master/ImageCropView

```
<imgcrop:ImageCropView HeightRequest="300" WidthRequest="300" x:Name="cropView"
    Source="http://photos2.insidercdn.com/iphone4scamera-111004-full.JPG">
</imgcrop:ImageCropView>
```

Comment: Can you please tell us whether your plugin is supporting for rectangle/square transformation. if so, please share some code sample.

Answer (score 2):

You can check this repo, which is great btw and will do what you want (and moreover with caching on images ... )
https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading